# How to do mulitple text search in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do multiple text search in same field

for example in sub_cat_seo_url field i want to get 'english-news' and 'business-news' filter by language and region

when i tried like below code it is not working

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":[
                  "english-news",
                  "business-news"
               ],
               "fields":[
                  "sub_cat_seo_url"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "lang":"en"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "region":"1"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For single text search it is working fine

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"english-news",
               "fields":[
                  "sub_cat_seo_url"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "lang":"en"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "region":"1"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please help what have to change in my code, to do multi text search in same field (or operation)

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "\"english-news\" AND \"business-news\"",
          "fields": [
            "sub_cat_seo_url"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "lang": "en"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "region": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no it is not working when i send like this "query": "\"english-news\" AND \"business-news\"", getting error, some mistake in sending, can you please tell me how send two text